# What ssis design pattern is good for flat file to table load

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Planning to import  1000s of text file to  sql server tables. All these files are having different structures and it goes to corresponding new tables in
SQl. Different methods coming in mind is using of Biml /creating ssis packages with number of data flows/using import wizard.

What is the ssis design pattern to achieve this in most time efficient way. This is  a onetime load though.

How to handle the failure ? : I am not considering the checkpoint because ,when Control Flow tasks are run in parallel checkpoints act a little erratically.

Comment: What have you tried so far to import the files? Are they delimited text files? Comma, Pipe, etc? Each one has a different structure? So there are 1000s of structures?

Comment: yes there are 1000s of structures and these are a pipe delimited files

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059397/handling-files-with-different-structure-for-each-loop-ssis?rq=1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830711/create-a-new-table-and-import-data-from-csv-file-into-sql-server-2005

Comment: Thanks.The  Import and Export tool in SQL Server would do.This is a one time load.So there is no need to create apackages for this 1:1 mapping

Comment: As a one time job, my advice would be to use whatever method you are most comfortable with.  If you already proficient with BIML this would probably be the fastest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you a starting point if you want to see what each file has for data, without opening every one of them. The DefaultDir will reside on your SQL Server that you are running from.

```
SELECT * FROM  
OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DefaultDir=C:\PathtoFiles',
'select * from FileName.csv');
```